# Bluez 5.48 clear cached devices

Tags: linux, qt, bluetooth, bluez

I'm currently developing a QT app on Mac OS and it is working fine.

However I build buildroot image for SAMA5D27 with WILC3000 wifi/ble.

The BlueZ version is 5.48 and the QT is 5.12.2.

The problem is when a device is scanned it remains in cache. I'm not able to filter the non-cached found devices using the [isCached()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbluetoothdeviceinfo.html#isCached) method provided by QT ( It always returns false. It just doesnt work )

How can I disable the BlueZ cache or just delete the previous scanns in QT?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The found devices are stored in /var/lib/bluetooth/.....
They can be deleted manually. But this is not very elegant. If you find a more elegant way via QT or bluez, tell us.